# ¿Cómo cambiar el idioma a español en plantilla de AdminBSBMaterialDesign-master, en Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, material-design

Estoy ultilizando AdminBSBMaterialDesign-master para el diseño de mi sitio hecho en symfony3. Pero este está totalmente en inglés. Necesito cambiar el idioma al menos para utilizar el calendario Datepicker.

Comment: En realidad no es el idioma de tu plantilla lo que debes cambiar sino el idioma de ese componente.

Comment: Intenta cuado llames a bootstrapMaterialDatePicker pasarle la opción **lang**: 'es'